# faceBook auto shows your friends Name while tagging or mensioning

Tags: java, android

when we add any status in facebook, it auto shows your friends Name, if name is half then it complete, it also gives us place name . HOw? I want to implement in my app like that it will search automatic its name to whose we want to tag after few word. plz help

Comment: https://engineering.linkedin.com/android/open-sourcing-spyglass-flexible-library-implementing-mentions-android

Comment: yes working , good library

Answer (score 0):

Use > `AutoCompleteTextView`

- it shows completion suggestions automatically while the user is typing.

Look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)

Comment: can any one give me api of this ? I mean "when we post any status it shows its autocomplete list  or we mension anyone name it complete give their name . I wanted to know all process" main thing is it shows all hints in whole text area anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/linkedin/Spyglass

read all documentation, every thing is here

Comment: https://engineering.linkedin.com/android/open-sourcing-spyglass-flexible-library-implementing-mentions-android                                                                         use this link I got from here and impleted